# FastReport. Перенос строк в ячейке при выводе в Excel

Tags: excel, fastreport, перенос

До недавнего времени работал с версией FastReport 2015.4.0.0. Для переноса строки использовал просто символ `\n`. В новом проекте версия другая: 2018.4.16.0 и с ней такой прием не проходит. Вместо переноса вставляется ASCII последовательность `_x000A_`.

Как исправить?

Comment: 10 - код символа переноса строки. Поможет?

Comment: нет. Заменяет его на ту же комбинацию x000A

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что для Excel символом переноса строки является комбинация символов  в данных `&#10;`. Пробел в начале - обязательно! Свойство `Wysiwyg` поля, в которое вставляется текст с переносом, должно быть `true`.

Однако, эта комбинация не работает для Word. Там - `\n`. Приходится по-разному готовить данные для разных форматов.

Comment: *для Excell символом переноса строки является комбинация символов* - в самом Excel достаточно символа 10. Это *FastReport* чудит.

Comment: Да, собственно, я про ФР и спрашивал. к Экселю претензий нет.